# Symfony 4 - The option "invalid_message" does not exist

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I use Symfony 4.1, and I try a simple usage of form builder :

```
    $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class)
        ->add('phone', TelType::class)
        ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, array(
            'type' => PasswordType::class,
            'invalid_message' => 'Passwords don\'t match',
            'options' => array('attr' => array('class' => 'password-field')),
            'required' => false,
            'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Password'),
            'second_options' => array('label' => 'Password confirmation'),
            'mapped' => false,
        ))
```

I got the error :

> The option "invalid_message" does not exist. Defined options are ....

I don't find any informations on it, I just tried to copy the example from Symfony Doc : https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html

Do I need to import something ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `invalid_message` option belong to `FormTypeValidatorExtension` which is loaded by `ValidatorExtension` when the `Validator` component is available.

You need to install this component to enable the validator options:

```
composer require symfony/validator
```